# language error on an EE 1 upgrade

Tags: error, ee2-upgrades, language

I've tried to do an upgrade on a 1.7.3 site and never seen this error before:

```
The language files needed for your current language selection () are unavailable. Please put the language pack in this folder: expressionengine/language/
```

I've tried upgrading to 2.6.1 and 2.5.5 and both give the same error.

Language files are definitely in place.

Can't find any refs online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems the language files got borked on a previous unsuccessful upgrade. Restored from a backup and it ran fine.